# How do I design a page based View for a collection of UserControls in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, architecture

Preface: It's a bit hard to explain my problem in the form of a question so let my explain below.

Context: I'm developing a UI for an audio mixer (see picture) and as part of that I have a row of 16 "Channel Strips" (a UserControl) each with a fader. In the model though, the mixer has 32 channels (+ Auxiliaries). To remove the need for a super large ItemsControl with a scroll bar then I want to implement a page system to switch which channels in the model the UI is bound too.

[image: Mock up of the UI.]
Mock up of the UI.

After some reading of examples on MVVM architecture I narrowed it down to too ways to implement this but I have problems with each.

1. Bind the Channel Strips in the UI directly to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel and then use property notifiers to bind that to the data in the model:

```xaml
<ItemsControl x:Name="FaderPane1_8" Background="{DynamicResource FaderPanel}" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Faders}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ChannelStrip MaxWidth="50" FaderValue="0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```cs
 public ObservableCollection<ChannelStrip> Faders
 {
    get { return _faders; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _faders, value); }
 }

 public void Init()
 {
    //Create a new mixer
    VMixer = new Mixer(32, 8, 8);

    VMixer.MixChannels.CollectionChanged += MixChannels_CollectionChanged;
 }
 //More code to handle "MixChannels_CollectionChanged" as well as changes from ViewModel to Model
```

ViewModel.cs

The problem is that this creates lots of event handlers for property changes in every direction as well as ends up with a copy of the faders in memory. All of this seems like a poor design to me but is what I have seen dictated by convention because it allows for complete separation of Model from ViewModel and View as well as no direct link from View to Model.

2. Bind directly to a part of the model and use the ViewModel to rebind the UI channel strips to a different set of channels every time the page is changed.
   This seems more sensible in that I'm not created unnecessary copies of data and events, and might result in less messy code.

```xaml
<Grid x:Name="FaderPane9_16" Background="{DynamicResource FaderPanel}" Margin="0" Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:ChannelStrip/>
                <local:ChannelStrip Grid.Column="1"/>
                <local:ChannelStrip Grid.Column="2"/>
                <local:ChannelStrip Grid.Column="3"/>
                <local:ChannelStrip Grid.Column="4"/>
                <local:ChannelStrip Grid.Column="5"/>
                <local:ChannelStrip Grid.Column="6"/>
                <local:ChannelStrip Grid.Column="7"/>
            </Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```cs
 public void UpdateFaderBindings(ChannelType faderMode, int faderModePage)
 {
     //[Code omitted for simplicity]

     for (int i = 0; i < channels; i++)
     {
         int newFaderIndex = -1;
         //[Code omitted for simplicity]

         Binding b = new Binding("VMixer.Channels[newFaderIndex].FaderValue");//I know this is wrong I'm trying to demonstrate the idea
         ChannelStrips[i].SetBinding(ChannelStrip.FaderValue, b);
     }
 }
```

ViewModel.cs

Both of these architectures clearly have their own disadvantages and after hours of reading I'm getting nowhere in deciding what the correct architecture in this situation is.

Comment: MVVM is not for save-every-byte-challenges, but for better separation, testing and maintaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write WPF airport check-in systems for a living, and I encounter this problem all the time in the form of aircraft seat selection. There isn't enough space to display all 525 seats of an A380, so I have to display sections of the fuselage and allow passengers to scroll through them. Similarly, a check-in kiosk may need to present 50 different airlines for a passenger to select from, so again paging is used to scroll through them.

What you're really try to do here is implement a form of virtualization. That, in turn, requires view logic. And whenever you have view logic that doesn't require direct interaction with an actual GUI element the correct place to put it is almost always in the view model layer. In a commercial application this is absolutely behavior you would want to unit test, but with option #2 you can't do that without the GUI elements actually being present.

The reason option #1 looks messy is because it is, despite being closer to pure MVVM. What you really should be doing is creating a 1:1 relation between your views and your view models. I personally would create a MixerViewModel class for each of your mixers (visible or no) containing information needed by just that mixer, and also maintain a list for the ones that are currently visible:

```
private IList<MixerViewModel> AllMixers;
public ObserveableCollection<MixerViewModel> VisibleMixers {get; set;} // would probably also need INPC
```

The first list is for all 32 of your mixers and gets created at start-up. That second list is what's currently visible, you populate it with elements from the first list whenever the current page changes. Doing it this way facilitates complete separation of concerns, it makes it very easy to change the total number of items (either in total, or visible at once) and you also now have the ability to unit-test. Yes, it means GUI items are being created and destroyed whenever the page changes, but that's how WPF has been designed to be used and as long as you don't go overboard your application will remain responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the first solution is more suitable but I would perhaps in addition try to avoid all handlers by simply creating 2 separate ItemsControls in UI (bound to the same ObservableCollection) on top of each other with second hidden and with buttons that change channels simply revert the visibility of both ItemsControls.